# Why Qt Stackwidget take ~2sec to populate but almost 8 sec to show?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm new to the Qt Framework and Qt Creator, I'm developing a Window GUI application. The base class is QtStackWidget, which then contains different labels, buttons, etc. There are more than 500 pages. When I do the time analysis, my ui->stackWidget->show() take about 8 seconds to load despite it only take  ~2 seconds to populate more than 500 pages.

Populating pages took 1504 milliseconds
Total pages:  548
Displaying gui took 8229 milliseconds
Displaying gui took 8229747100 nanoseconds

Is there anyway to speed up the show() function?

Comment: I guess the most time demanding operation will be layouting of all the 500 pages. Which I guess is done just before show. So the best way to speed it up is to not create 500 pages but only the one which will be shown. And when you switch to another page, create that page. Etc.

Comment: "There are more than 500 pages" Why?